# Error during serialization using in Custom MediaType Formatter

Tags: model-view-controller, json.net, mediatypeformatter

i implemented custom media-type formatter with per request logic

```
public class JsonPermissionBasedFormatter : PartialJsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public override MediaTypeFormatter GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
        {
            User user = request.GetOwinContext()?.Request.Get<User>("AuthorizationFilter:CurrentUser");
            var formatter = (PartialJsonMediaTypeFormatter)base.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance(type, request, mediaType);
             formatter.SerializerSettings = SerializerSettings;
            formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new PermissionBasedContractResolver(user);
            return formatter;
        }
    }
```

public class PermissionBasedContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        private readonly User _user;

```
    public PermissionBasedContractResolver(User user)
    {
        _user = user;
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy
        {
            ProcessDictionaryKeys = true,
            OverrideSpecifiedNames = true
        };
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        if (member == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(member));
        }
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        var propertyInfo = member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            if (!PermissionsHelper.IsPropertyVisibleForUser(propertyInfo, _user))
            {
                property.ShouldSerialize = DoNotSerialize;
            }
        }
        return property;
    }

    static bool DoNotSerialize(object o)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public static bool IsPropertyVisibleForUser(PropertyInfo info, User user)
    {
        if (info.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreDataMemberAttribute>() != null) 
return false;
        if (user == null) return true;
        var permissionForExportAttribute = 
info.GetCustomAttribute<VisibleForAttribute>();
        if (permissionForExportAttribute != null)
        {
            return 
user.HasPermission(permissionForExportAttribute.Permission);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

PermissionBasedContractResolver add custom logic for serialization which depend on user rights. For example user with admin rights receives additional properties in json, which ordinary user do not.
But if run requests in the following manner:

```
Parallel.For(1, 10000, _ =>
            {
                Get(ordinaryUser, isAdmin: false);
                Get(adminUser, isAdmin: true);
            });
```

occasionally got for ordinaryUser json properties availiable only for admins. i dont understand how it can happens. 
Problem can be reproduce only under some load, if run requests manually via postman - all is ok. Can you tell what it can be or give advices how to investigate such problem.

Comment: 1) What is `PartialJsonMediaTypeFormatter`?  Is it [this](https://github.com/dotarj/PartialResponse/blob/master/src/PartialResponse.Net.Http/Formatting/PartialJsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs)?  2) Can you share a version of `PermissionsHelper.IsPropertyVisibleForUser()` that reproduces the problem?  Does it cache any data statically?

Comment: 1) Yes, it is standard implementation from PartialResponse.Net.Http.Formatting 2) No, it don't cache any information, source code added.